# Amazon SES User policy for sending limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I want to create an IAM user account to limit the number of emails sent during a month to ie 100000, but reading in the docs I can't find any policy that accomplishes this,

The only thing close to that is to [limit the possible actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-policy-examples.html#sending-authorization-policy-example-action) to "sendEmail" and "sendRawEmail" like the policy below..any idea?

```
{
  "Id": "ExamplePolicy",    
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ControlAction",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:888888888888:identity/example.com",
      "Principal": {"AWS": ["123456789012"]},
      "Action": ["SES:SendRawEmail"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible: [Creating IAM Policies for Access to Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html) Restrictions in IAM policy are:

> There are three reasons you might use IAM with Amazon SES:
>
> To restrict the email-sending action.
>
> To restrict the "From",
> recipient, and "Return-Path" addresses of the emails that the user
> sends.
>
> To control general aspects of API usage such as the time period
> during which a user is permitted to call the APIs that they are
> authorized to use.

Answer (score 0):

helloV is Right, apparently you cant do that what you can do is set Sending Quota.

Refer (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-limits.html)